# Create relationship to achieve the query

Tags: filter, powerbi, visualization

I have these two tables' achievements and community interactions. What I want to do is when I click on achievement type from bar chat it shows me the result according to that in the tables
the content of the table is the user id and post_content from the community intentions table, and the bar chart content is the user id and achievement type. Please let me know if ou need further details
[visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvOwY.jpg)
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8PIq.jpg)